# Process a list of filenames to split directory and basename

Tags: centos, text-processing, filenames

I have a file containing a bunch of filenames:

```
$ cat test_as1
/var/incoming/foo.txt
/var/incoming/bar.txt
/var/incoming/baz.txt
```

For each filename, I want to print the directory name and the base filename, comma-separated. For example:

```
/var/incoming,foo.txt
/var/incoming,bar.txt
/var/incoming,baz.txt
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You might want to check out the `basename` and `dirname` commands

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over the file and then print the parts before and after the last slash with parameter expansion:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s,%s\n' "${line%/*}" "${line##*/}"
done < test_as1
```

`"${line%/*}"` removes the shortest match of `/*` from the end of the line, and `"${line##*/}"` removes the longest match of `*/` from the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)\//\1,/' -i /var/incoming/new_item.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @hhoke1 mentioned in a comment above, you can use the `basename` and `dirname` commands:

```
$ basename /var/incoming/new_items.txt
new_items.txt

$ dirname /var/incoming/new_items.txt
/var/incoming
```

Comment: Thanks Andy basename /var/incoming/new_items.txt and dirname /var/incoming/new_items.txt seem to do the trick. Do you know how I can do it for about 150 similar items

Comment: @user210912 Can you tell us what you're trying to do?

Comment: Edited the question with what I believe user210912 is looking for based on a comment thread